# Bash Scripting - Reading variables line by line

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a single column file with values like:

```
40 
58
76
```

I want to make a script to read separately all this values but I don`t know the ways to do this via Bash script.

I want  the echo display something like this:

```
LINE 1 : value 40
LINE 2 : value 58
LINE 3 : value 76
```

Answer (score 9):

For things like this, you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print "LINE", NR, ": value", $0}' file
LINE 1 : value 40
LINE 2 : value 58
LINE 3 : value 76
```

`awk` automatically reads one line at the time. `NR` holds the line number and `$0` the full content of the line, so you just need to print those.

But if you really want Bash, say something like:

```
line=1
while IFS= read -r value; do
  echo "LINE $line : value $value"
  (( line ++ ))
done < file
```

This loops through the content of the file `file` using a `while` loop that is fed with `< file`. Every cycle, the value of one line is stored in the variable `$value`. Then, it is a matter of printing the result together with incrementing the variable `$line` to keep track of the line number.

See more info in BashFAQ: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

Via `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s%s%s%s\n","LINE ",NR," : value ",$1}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
40 
58
76

$ awk '{printf "%s%s%s%s\n","LINE ",NR," : value ",$1}' foo
LINE 1 : value 40
LINE 2 : value 58
LINE 3 : value 76
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Bash loop:

```
while read -r line; do let lineNumber++; echo "LINE $lineNumber : value $line"; done < file.txt
```

output:

```
LINE 1 : value 40
LINE 2 : value 58
LINE 3 : value 76
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this natively in Bash > 4 using the `mapfile` / `readarray` built-in:

```bsh
mapfile -t x <in
```

```
$ cat in
40 
58
76
$ mapfile -t x <in
$ echo ${x[@]}
40 58 76
$ echo ${x[0]}
40
$ echo ${x[1]}
58
$ echo ${x[2]}
76
```

To print the elements of the array one by one using that format, you can use a `for` loop:

```bsh
i=1; for element in ${x[@]}; do echo "LINE $i : value $element"; ((i++)); done
```

```
$ i=1; for element in ${x[@]}; do echo "LINE $i : value $element"; ((i++)); done
LINE 1 : value 40
LINE 2 : value 58
LINE 3 : value 76
```